# Inverse a non-square matrix with high precision

Tags: python, numpy, precision

I am trying to solve a problem of A*b = c, where A and c are:

```
A = np.block([[X_matrix - rho_0, np.zeros((3, 3)), np.zeros((3, 3))],
              [np.zeros((3, 3)), X_matrix - rho_1, np.zeros((3, 3))],
              [np.zeros((3, 3)), np.zeros((3, 3)), X_matrix - rho_2],
              [I, I, I]])

c = np.block([[np.zeros((3, 3))],
              [np.zeros((3, 3))],
              [np.zeros((3, 3))],
              [I]])
```

Since A is a non-square matrix here, I can only use

```
A_inv = np.linalg.pinv(A)
# Solve for b
b = np.matmul(A_inv, c)
```

However, this method is not very precise as `print(np.linalg.norm(np.matmul(A, b) - c))` will give 0.212871998042824. May I ask whether there is a more precise method to obtain b?

I have tried `np.linalg.lstsq`
but it seems to give the same result as `np.linalg.pinv(A)`

Also, it seems that `A**-1` from mpmath will arrive at the error: `ValueError: only powers of square matrices are defined`.

Comment: Non-square matrices, by definition, don’t have inverses. What you are asking for doesn’t exist mathematically

Comment: "I have tried `np.linalg.lstsq` but it seems to give the same result as `np.linalg.pinv(A)`." If lstsq can't find a `b` that works in that equation, that means there is no `b` that will work. That does happen sometimes.

Comment: the pinv gives you a result that would minimize the errors but those errors while in general be not zero. You have more equations then variables so in general there will be no solution that exactly fits, except for specially constructed cases.